# How to add database table values into a javascript table?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, postgresql

so that's my question.

I have a database called Storage with a table named products, that table has 20 rows of products with the following fields (name, description, price, quantity).

in my javascript code, i'm using XMLHttpRequest to ask the server for this information, the server (java servlet) executes the query "SELECT * FROM products" to get all values and save them in a variable in server side

my question goes, how can i get that data from the java servlet, send it to my javascript code (client side) and create a table with those values.

this is my attempt to generate the table in client side to add the values.

```
`function generateTable()
{
    table.style.border = "1";
    table.style.borderColor = "red";
    table.style.alignment = "center";

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        table.insertRow();

        for(int j = 0; j<4; j++)
        {
            table.rows[i].insertCell();
        }
    }

    table.style.display = "block";
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}`
```

Notes: i have to use raw Javascript, Java, and if needed AngularJS.

Comment: When you get the results from the server side script, i.e., the return status of XMLHttpRequest is 'ok', parse the data and append it to the HTML using javascript. Your question is way too generic though. Be a bit specific :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. unfortunately we are not a script library. We provide assistance to users that have a piece of their own coding which is not working correctly and want us to help them with it , or ran into a quirk or strange behavior while coding and want an explanation for it. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: We really don't have enough information to answer your questions effectively. It sounds like you're in need of three parts in order to make this work, and you only have one. Namely: you need a database to get your information, which you have. You need a backend API that'll serve your request when it receives an XMLHttpRequest, which you don't have. And you need a front-end interface to receive it, which you don't have. Sounds like a big task. I'd recommend you tackle one of these problems and ask questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean insert a row to the table, and you want to use AJAX way. 
AJAX is when you do not refresh the page, only JavaScript communicates in the background.

1. post an AJAX message to a servlet
2. implement the doPost() method and return a Stirng value, it could be a JSON
3. implement the Javascript callback where the AJAX completed